# Django rest framework import error in on django.test.client

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, importerror

I'm using google app engine dev server for python running on mac os.
The project I'm running is an appengine django project using djangae and django rest framework.

Everything in the project works fine, however as soon as a declare an import relating to the rest_framework I get an error regarding `django.test.client` eventhough I'm not running any tests at the moment.

The import I try to do is 'from rest_framework.decoraters import api_view', as soon as I make this import or any other import relating to the rest framework.

This is the error I get with every import I make that involves the rest framework.

```
ERROR    2017-02-27 10:19:08,019 base.py:256] Internal Server Error: /_ah/warmup
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 223, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/core/middleware/url_definition.py", line 32, in process_response
    response = redirect('%s/' % request.path)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/shortcuts.py", line 116, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/shortcuts.py", line 205, in resolve_url
    return urlresolvers.reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 578, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 432, in _reverse_with_prefix
    self._populate()
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 284, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 401, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/core/urls.py", line 34, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('pages.urls'), name='pages.urls')
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/pages/urls.py", line 31, in <module>
    url(r'^myapp/', include('pages.myapp.urls', namespace='rest_framework'), name="pages.myapp"),
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/pages/myapp/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    url(r'^finance/', include('pages.myapp.finance.urls'), name='pages.myapp.finance'),
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/pages/myapp/finance/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    url(r'^api/', include('pages.myapp.finance.api.urls'), name='pages.myapp.finance.api.urls'),
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/pages/myapp/finance/api/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    url(r'^service/', include('pages.myapp.finance.api.service.urls'), name='pages.myapp.finance.api.service'),
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/pages/myapp/finance/api/service/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    url(r'^user/', include('pages.myapp.finance.api.service.user.urls'),
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/pages/myapp/finance/api/service/user/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pages.myapp.finance.api.service.user import functions
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/pages/myapp/finance/api/service/user/functions.py", line 5, in <module>
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/rest_framework/views.py", line 19, in <module>
    from rest_framework.request import Request
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/rest_framework/request.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/rest_framework/settings.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.test.signals import setting_changed
File "/Users/MyUser/git/project-name/src/lib/django/test/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 999, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named django.test.client
```

Comment: How you are including these libraries?. Seems like the django version that you're using doesn't have `django.test.client` which is required by DRF: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/1c437a793c3f3cedb1aa53f0cccec23a96cc3f34/rest_framework/settings.py#L23

Comment: @chachan I add django to the python path on project init with a basic fix path setup, the django version that I am using is `Django 1.8.2`, and does in face contain `django.test.client` but regardless it says it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run into import errors like this on app engine be sure to check your `skip_files` in app.yaml.

For example:

```
skip_files:
  - ^(.*/)?.*/test/.*$
```

Makes the 'django/test' folder not importable in your dev environment and the folder will not be deployed to app engine.